# PHP - How to get last segment of URL string

Tags: php

I'm trying to extract the last segment of this URL: http://test.com/blog/#segmentIwant (the #segmentIwant is the string I want). The hash tag is generated from a link within the website. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: you can use explode() function of php using the # as a delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well while you load a page with # tag, php does not know it as # tags on url are treated by basically javascript and are not sent to server. But with a simple AJAX request you can send the value to server on loading the page and get the response through that AJAX response.

To grab the url with Javascript:

```
var url = document.URL;
```

And try [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function to get the last part of the sent url with PHP code.

```
 echo basename( "http://test.com/blog/#segmentIwant" );
```

Or a simple function in javascript to do it:

```
var url = document.URL;
hashed_string = url.split("#");
alert(hashed_string[1]);
```

Comment: Please do a favor while voting -1, post a comment too to help the poster avoid the reason of -1 next time.

Comment: Wasnt me who downvoted but I presume that it is because PHP cannot read the HASH at all!

Comment: @InGodITrust: yes, I know. but my solution was based on a string. And we can still pass the url to a php script via ajax if we want. Technically there is nothing wrong, I believe. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: AJAX wouldnt help you, because the receieving PHP script still wouldnt know about the HASH unless you put in a `$_GET` variable

Comment: @InGodITrust sorry I think you didn't get me. I'd send the url I grabbed with JS with `$_GET` or `$_POST` of course. Otherwise why I'll create an ajax request, I wonder :)

Comment: That'll work fine, take a +1 for that. Have a nice evening!

Answer (score 5):

PHP cannot read the hash, the server doesnt even recieve it at all!

Comment: Is there any way to extract the hash? jQuery?

Comment: @user2069381 sure, with pure javascript use, `window.location.hash;`